# Funciones Importadas y trabajar con dos archivos.js

Tags: javascript, firebase

He creado un servidor con fireBase y estoy practicando, he conseguido crear unos recuadros, uno para crear una entrada al servidor y al darle al botón se grabe en firebase y ademas me aparezca en el DOM, luego cuando aparece en este tienes dos botones uno que borra la entrada y otro que quiero que actualice los datos mediante "inputs" pero no consigo que este ultimo funcione por que no se como recoger los valores. si no crease los inputs podría hacerlo desde el primer recaudo pero no es esa la idea, a ver si podéis guiarme por el camino correcto!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CRUD Firebase</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/pulse/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-L7+YG8QLqGvxQGffJ6utDKFwmGwtLcCjtwvonVZR/Ba2VzhpMwBz51GaXnUsuYbj" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="position: relative; left: 484px;" ><h1>Ingresa aqui la tarea</h1></div>
        <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-6  offset-md-4" style="max-width: 20rem;display:flex;flex-direction: column;">
            <div class="card-header">Formulario Tareas</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form id="task-form">
                    <input type="text" id="task-title" class="form-control" placeholder="Título de la tarea"
                        autofocus>
                    <textarea id="task-description" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripción de la tarea" cols="10"
                        rows="5"></textarea>
                    <br>

                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar Tarea" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="task-button">

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h3>Listado de tareas existente</h3>

        <script src="utils.js" type="module" defer></script>
        <script src="index.js" type="module" defer></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

tengo dos .js

```js
//Me traigo mi db firestore
import { getTasks, insertTask, deleteTask, updateTask} from "./utils.js";
//console.log(db);
//Extraigo todos los documentos de tasks y creo tarjetas con ellos
getTasks();


//Obtenemos el form y capturamos el submit
const form = document.getElementById("task-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const task = {
        title: form["task-title"].value,
        description: form["task-description"].value
    }

    insertTask(task);
})


const buttonsCardD = document.getElementsByName("delete");
buttonsCardD.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        var divDelete = element.parentNode.parentNode;
        document.body.removeChild(divDelete);
        //console.log("Estoy borrando la tarea: "+element.id);
        deleteTask(element.id);
    })
});

const buttonsCardA = document.getElementsByName('añadir');
const inputNam = document.getElementsByName('formulario')
buttonsCardA.forEach(element => {
   
    element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const taskIn = {
            title: inputNam["tituloTar"].value,
            description: inputNam["descriptionTar"].value
        }
       
        updateTask(element.id, taskIn);
    })
});
```

y este otro

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs, doc, setDoc, deleteDoc,updateDoc } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-firestore.js';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "task"));

function createCard(id, task, ) {
    //<div class="card text-white bg-info mb-6  offset-md-4" style="max-width: 20rem;">
    const principalDiv = document.createElement('div');
    principalDiv.setAttribute("class", "card bg-light mb-3");
    principalDiv.style = "max-width: 20rem;";
    principalDiv.setAttribute("name", id);
    principalDiv.setAttribute("id", id);
    //<div class="card-header">Formulario Tareas</div>
    const headerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const contentDiv = document.createTextNode("Id: " + id);
    headerDiv.setAttribute("class", "card-header");

    headerDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);
    principalDiv.appendChild(headerDiv);
    // <div class="card-body">
    const bodyDiv = document.createElement('form');
    bodyDiv.setAttribute("name", "formulario")
    const pTitle = document.createElement("p");
    const pTitleText = document.createTextNode("Title: " + task.title);


    const pTitleInText = document.createElement("input");
    pTitleInText.type = "text";
    pTitleInText.value =  task.title ;
    pTitleInText.placeholder = "Modifica Titulo";
    pTitleInText.setAttribute("name", "tituloTar");
   


    // const pTitleIn = document.createTextNode('placeholder' + task.title);
    const hr = document.createElement('hr');
    const pDesc = document.createElement("p");
    const pDescText = document.createTextNode("Description: " + task.description);


    const pDescInText = document.createElement("input");
    pDescInText.type = "text";
    pDescInText.value = task.description;
    pDescInText.placeholder = "Modifica Descripción";
    pDescInText.setAttribute("name", "descriptionTar");
  


    pTitle.appendChild(pTitleText);
    // pTitleIn.appendChild(pTitleInText)
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pTitle);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pTitleInText);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(hr);
    pDesc.appendChild(pDescText);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pDesc);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pDescInText);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(hr);

    var inputAdd = document.createElement('input');
    inputAdd.type = "button";
    inputAdd.value = "Añadir";
    inputAdd.setAttribute("name", "añadir");
    inputAdd.setAttribute("id", id);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(inputAdd)


    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "button";
    input.value = "Borrar Tarea";
    input.class = "btn";
    input.setAttribute("name", "delete");
    input.setAttribute("id", id);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(input);

    principalDiv.appendChild(bodyDiv);

    document.body.appendChild(principalDiv);
    const br = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(br);

}

export function getTasks() {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        createCard(doc.id, doc.data());
    });
}
function generateRandomIdTask(num) {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let result = '';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }

    return result;
}
export async function insertTask(task) {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "task", generateRandomIdTask(20)), task);
    alert("Insertada la tarea: " + task.title);
}

export async function deleteTask(id) {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, "task", id));
    alert("Borrada la tarea: " + id);
}

export async function updateTask(id, task){
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "task", id),task);
    location.reload()
    alert("Actaulaización: " + id);
}
```

Comment: Has probado a cambiar `form["task-title"].value,` por `document.getElementById("task-title").value` ?

Comment: hola!! si lo he probado eso es otra forma de llamar a los inputs del .card del html previamente creado y necesito llamar a los inputs creados en el js

Answer (score 1):

Podrías ponerle una clase a los inputs eses que creas en el js.

```
const pDescInText = document.createElement("input");
pDescInText.type = "text";
pDescInText.value = task.description;
pDescInText.classList.Add("input-pDescInText");
pDescInText.placeholder = "Modifica Descripción";
pDescInText.setAttribute("name", "descriptionTar");

const pTitleInText = document.createElement("input");
pTitleInText.type = "text";
pDescInText.classList.Add("input-pTitleInText");
pTitleInText.value =  task.title ;
pTitleInText.placeholder = "Modifica Titulo";
pTitleInText.setAttribute("name", "tituloTar");
```

Luego en el sitio que quieras recoger los valores de los inputs haces:

```
inputsTitleInText = document.querySelectorAll(".input-pTitleInText");
inputsTitleInText.forEach(x => {
     const valor = x.value;
     //resto del código que quieras hacer....
})
```

Y lo mismo con los otros inputs, los `pDescInText`

Comment: Muchas gracias he cogido tu idea de hacer la llamada mediante querySelector pero si te fijas el botón que antes utilizaba para actualizar (function updateTask) ya copia el id de la tarjeta por lo que después de romper mi mente tres veces lo conseguí

Answer (score 1):

He realizado unas mejoras y ya consigo que el programa funciones como deseo.

```js
//Me traigo mi db firestore
import { getTasks, insertTask, deleteTask, updateTask} from "./utils.js";
//console.log(db);
//Extraigo todos los documentos de tasks y creo tarjetas con ellos
getTasks();


//Obtenemos el form y capturamos el submit
const form = document.getElementById("task-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const task = {
        title: form["task-title"].value,
        description: form["task-description"].value
    }

    insertTask(task);
})


const buttonsCardD = document.getElementsByName("delete");
buttonsCardD.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        var divDelete = element.parentNode.parentNode;
        document.body.removeChild(divDelete);
        //console.log("Estoy borrando la tarea: "+element.id);
        deleteTask(element.id);
    })
});

const buttonsCardA = document.getElementsByName('añadir');



buttonsCardA.forEach(element => {
    const inputNam = document.getElementsByName(element.id)
    
       
  
    element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(document.querySelector('.tituloTar').value)
        
        
        const taskIn = {
            title: document.querySelector('.tituloTar').value,
            description: document.querySelector('.descriptionTar').value
            
        }
       
        updateTask(element.id, taskIn);
        // updateTask(element.id, taskIn);
    })
});
```

con estos últimos retoques ya solo me queda hacerlo mas atractivo para el usuario

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs, doc, setDoc, deleteDoc,updateDoc } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-firestore.js';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "task"));

function createCard(id, task, i) {
    //<div class="card text-white bg-info mb-6  offset-md-4" style="max-width: 20rem;">
    const principalDiv = document.createElement('div');
    principalDiv.setAttribute("class", "card bg-light mb-3");
    principalDiv.style = "max-width: 20rem;";
    principalDiv.setAttribute("name", id);
    principalDiv.setAttribute("id", i);
    //<div class="card-header">Formulario Tareas</div>
    const headerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const contentDiv = document.createTextNode("Id: " + id);
    headerDiv.setAttribute("class", "card-header");

    headerDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);
    principalDiv.appendChild(headerDiv);
    // <div class="card-body">
    const bodyDiv = document.createElement('form');
    bodyDiv.setAttribute("name", "formulario")
    bodyDiv.setAttribute("class", "formulario")
    // const pTitle = document.createElement("p");
    // const pTitleText = document.createTextNode("Title: " + task.title);


    const pTitleInText = document.createElement("input");
    pTitleInText.type = "text";
    pTitleInText.value =  task.title ;
    // pTitleInText.placeholder = "Modifica Titulo";
    pTitleInText.setAttribute("name", "tituloTar");
    pTitleInText.setAttribute("class", "tituloTar");
   


    // const pTitleIn = document.createTextNode('placeholder' + task.title);
    const hr = document.createElement('hr');
    // const pDesc = document.createElement("p");
    // const pDescText = document.createTextNode("Description: " + task.description);


    const pDescInText = document.createElement("input");
    pDescInText.type = "text";
    pDescInText.value = task.description;
    // pDescInText.placeholder = "Modifica Descripción";
    pDescInText.setAttribute("name", "descriptionTar");
    pDescInText.setAttribute("class", "descriptionTar");
  


   
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pTitleInText);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(hr);
  
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pDescInText);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(hr);

    var inputAdd = document.createElement('input');
    inputAdd.type = "button";
    inputAdd.value = "Modificar";
    inputAdd.setAttribute("name", "añadir");
    inputAdd.setAttribute("class", "boton");
    inputAdd.setAttribute("id", id);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(inputAdd)


    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "button";
    input.value = "Borrar Tarea";
   
    input.setAttribute("name", "delete");
    input.setAttribute("class", "boton");
    input.setAttribute("id", id);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(input);

    principalDiv.appendChild(bodyDiv);

    document.body.appendChild(principalDiv);
    const br = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(br);

}

export function getTasks() {
    let i = 0;
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // console.log(doc.id);
        createCard(doc.id, doc.data(), i);
        i++
    });
}


function generateRandomIdTask(num) {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let result = '';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }

    return result;
}
export async function insertTask(task) {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "task", generateRandomIdTask(20)), task);
    location.reload()
    alert("Insertada la tarea: " + task.title);
}

export async function deleteTask(id) {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, "task", id));
    alert("Borrada la tarea: " + id);
}

export async function updateTask(id, task){
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "task", id),task);
    location.reload()
    alert("Actaulaización: " + id);
}
```